# scipy stats kstest against x=y?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

This is something I've been confused about for a while and I was hoping for some assistance.

I'm trying to use `scipy.stats.kstest` to test my distribution against another distribution which is simply `x=y` so that I can get a p-value. In the examples online it gives something like:

```
>>> x = np.linspace(-15, 15, 9)
>>> scipy.stats.kstest(x, 'norm')
(0.44435602715924361, 0.038850142705171065)
```

but I'm not sure how I can modify the expected distribution from `norm` to `x=y`? Also, my 'real' distribution has both x and y values (it's a cdf of a uniform distribution). How would I plug it into this?

Comment: when you say "x=y" are you talking about a standard uniform cdf (whose equation would indeed be y=x between 0 and 1) or are you talking about a second sample? It's not really clear what you have there

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for `scipy.stats.ks_2samp`:

> This is a two-sided test for the null hypothesis that 2 independent
>   samples are drawn from the same continuous distribution.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
np.random.seed(123)

# Draw random samples from two normal distributions
#     with different means/stdevs.  The resulting pvalue
#     be low (high significance/reject the null).
rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(size=400, loc=0., scale=1)
rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(size=400, loc=0.5, scale=1.5)
p_lo = stats.ks_2samp(rvs1, rvs2)[1]
print(p_lo)
# 1.29793098188e-10

# Same test for two random samples drawn from same distribution
#     should yield high p value.
rvs3 = stats.norm.rvs(size=400, loc=0.01, scale=1)
p_hi = stats.ks_2samp(rvs1, rvs3)[1]
print(p_hi)
# 0.855599637503
```